# edittext not taking input when popupwindow is open

Tags: android, android-edittext, popupwindow

i have a edittext when i click on the edittext the popup window appears but when i try to type anything in edittext it does not take the input 
i have to dismiss the popup and then have to type

```
   PopupWindow popUp = popupWindowsort(v, mainproductlist);
            popUp.showAsDropDown(v, 0, 0);

   private PopupWindow popupWindowsort(View v, List catalog) {

    // initialize a pop up window type
    PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(v, 
   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
   true);

     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), 
  android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, catalog);
    // the drop down list is a list view
    ListView listViewSort = new ListView(getContext());
    // set our adapter and pass our pop up window contents
    listViewSort.setAdapter(adapter);

    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
    // some other visual settings for popup window
//        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
 //        popupWindow.update();
    popupWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    // 


 popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable
(R.drawable.white) 
 );
    popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // set the listview as popup content
    popupWindow.setContentView(listViewSort);

    return popupWindow;
  }
```

Comment: it's because you have lost focus to the edit text once dialog appears. it seems to be an unusual condition where you need input in background view while having dialog in front. what you can do is add a edit text in dialog and whatever you type there just  pass on to the background edit text via some callback.

Comment: but it is not a custom dialogue it is a popup window how can i add a edittext in it

Comment: even if it's a popup window you can add a view. currently, you must be showing something in your pop window there only add another edit text view. Or just create an xml with required view and use pop window's method setContentView to set the layout and work like normal view.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way set `popupWindow.isFocusable = false`,but when you start typing popup may dismissed. So you need add `popupWindow.isOutsideTouchable = false`, and close popupWindow programmatically.